# How to pre-load View Controllers?

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

So I have a TabBarController with 3 children VCs. My problem is that ViewControllers 2 and 3 take a second to load which kind of ruins the experience for me. To remedy this, I want to pre-load VCs 2 and 3 at the same time as 1. Is this possible? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load All TabBar Views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202737/load-all-tabbar-views)

Comment: Hi @MaksimPavlov!

I tried his solution but my app would crash on the first line I put in `- (void)loadView`. Would you happen to know of another way to achieve this?