# iOS - Lifecycle using NSNotificationCenter

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsnotificationcenter

I have an iOS (Objective C) application which has a bottom tab layout.
My following setup is working well, except when the second tab was not already loaded. My first viewcontroller (first tab) calls a observed method from the secondviewcontroller:

VC1:

```
-(void) callmethodVC2 {

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"MYFUNC" object:nil];
//switch to 2nd Tab
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;

}
```

VC2: 
in `viewDidLoad()` I register:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(loadSomething) name:@"MYFUNC" object:nil];
```

later in the VC2 I implement the observed method:

```
-(void) loadSomething {...}
```

So VC1 calls the method via NotifacationCenter -> the tabbar switches as expected and the method works great but **only** if I visited the second Tab
before.

What I guess is that when I visited the second VC before the viewDidLoad method is loaded and there is the registered observe-method! So if I do not visit the VC2 before the viewDidLoad method is not called and also no observer method is registered.

How can I "preload" the second VC in my first VC, is it the right way to push the second VC? And how is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, `viewDidLoad` is only called once, the first time the view is displayed on screen. You should register you observer in the initializer instead of doing it in `viewDidLoad`.

If you use a storyboard :

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loadSomething) name:@"MYFUNC" object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

If your view controller is instantiated programatically:

```
- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loadSomething) name:@"MYFUNC" object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thank you - that is what I needed to know!

Answer (score 1):

i think you just need preload your view controllers to solve your issue. I have found for you the same [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9203007/2529869) as I used before.